# Как исправить ошибку throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event при запуске сборки?

Tags: vue.js, gulp, webpack, npm

gulp development

```
[14:01:37] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\gulpfile.js
[14:01:37] Starting 'stylesheets'...
[14:01:37] Starting 'js'...
[14:01:37] Starting 'image'...
[14:01:37] Starting 'html'...
[14:01:37] Starting 'watch'...
[14:01:37] Finished 'watch' after 35 ms
[14:01:37] Starting 'server'...
[14:01:37] Finished 'server' after 19 ms

events.js:170
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^
Error: "java" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.
```

Answer (score 0):

Закройте nodejs app , работающий в другом shell. Перезагрузите terminal и снова запустите программу.

источник: [Node.js – events js 72 throw er unhandled 'error' event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22960703/4827341)

Comment: nodejs app ,у меня нету другого shell.,я открывал в php шторме пробовал,перезагрузил компьютер и попробовал в vs code и все равно эта ошибка

Comment: нашел в этом фале прада строка под другим номером 139

может кто подскажет , что дальше делать?

C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\node_modules\events\events.js// Note: The comments on the `throw` lines are intentional, they show
      // up in Node's output if this results in an unhandled exception.
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event